# How to silence Alertmanager specific rule?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have an alert concerning the increase in load of the CPU of my servers. Every day, one of them, a jenkins, with the builds, causes alerts.
I would like to mute them, because I know full well that during these builds the load is high. However, I do not want to delete this alert.
So I put the alert in silent mode via alertmanager, but I still have 30 alerts every day that are useless.

[image]

I don't understand why the silent still works.
Do I have to make an inhibit rule as :

```
inhibit_rules:
- target_match:
     alertname: 'HostHighCpuLoad'
  source_match:
     alertname: 'HostHighCpuLoad'
  equal: ['192.168.0.247']
```

Is it right?

Comment: How exactly did you create the silence thing? You didn't forget to change silence duration, did you? Also, silencing an alert will only make it disappear from notification channels (email, chat, whatever you use), it will remain visible in alertmanager and prometheus.

Comment: I used silence button in the alertmanager webUI. This mode works for the other silence as services like smartd off. But not for the kenjins cpu.

Comment: Judging by the screenshot you showed up there, the silence worked. Although by default in only lasts 2 hours, after that it is expired (=deleted). Have you changed that duration?

Comment: I put duration for 9 weeks....If silence is working, I don't understand why I receive alerting mail. Maybe, I can force it in alertmanager.yml ?

Comment: Well if it's not duration then I can conceive two possibilities: 1) some labels don't match (try to be less specific, a match by `alertname` and  `instance` should be enough); 2) maybe you have a second alertmanager, where you did not create a silence?

Comment: "equal" should contain label name, not it's value (see https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#inhibit_rule). Maybe it would work with:
`equal: ['instance']`?